# Full page overlay drag and drop jQuery

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, overlay

I'm trying to add a full page overlay when someone is entering the window with a file. 
This is working but when I add the overlay, it immediately fires the `'dragleave'` event because the overlay blocks the drag. This results in a flickering-effect.

Browser compatibility :
- Chrome and Safari seem to have this issue
- Firefox has this issue when you hold the cursor still, when moving : no problem. 
- IE9 seems to work

I want to become the same as on [imgur.com](http://www.imgur.com).
If you drag a file to their page it shows an overlay without flickering or such.

**First solution**

```
$(window).bind('dragover', dragover);
$(window).bind('drop', drop);
$(window).bind('dragleave', dragleave);
```

[Full example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tdhulster/sQ6Es/)

**Second solution**

I also tried to set the 'dragleave' event to the '.overlay' class as you can see here:

```
$('.overlay').bind('dragleave', dragleave);
```

[Full example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tdhulster/ksmhr/)

But if you hover over the paragraph in the divs it also sends an 'dragleave' event.

Does someone know how to prevent this? 
Or how to a 'dragleave' only when you leave the browser window?

Thanks!

Comment: On IE9 and Firefox i can't see the flickering effect! which browser do you use?

Comment: I'm using Chrome and Safari :) i'll put it in the original post ;) thanks

Comment: So in IE9 and Firefox the second or first solution is working correctly ?

Comment: both solutions work in IE9 and Firefox

Comment: If i move my cursor in Firefox it works, but if I hold still my cursor in Firefox it has the flickering effect again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding a timeout on the Hide helps preventing the flickering!

```
function dragover(event) {
    clearTimeout(tid);
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.overlay').show();
}

function dragleave(event) {
    tid = setTimeout(function(){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('.overlay').hide();
    }, 300);
}
```

I edited your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yApUZ/

Comment: This works pretty good ! 
The only thing that rests is : there's a delay when leaving the browser window : the overlay stays for another 300 ms :) can I check when mouse leaves the browser ?

Comment: Thanks for helping ! I posted the complete answer again for those who have the same problem later !

Comment: Instead of copying Nikolaj's answer to add a part of your question and accepting it as you provided the answer, you could have just edited his.

Answer (score 8):

I came across a better solution in my optinion, no need to use timeouts which I tend not to like.

If you set your overlay to have CSS property

```
pointer-events:none
```

it won't affect drag events on the window when showing up and you can achieve the same effect

Comment: Works flawlessly, this should be the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Nikolaj I came to the correct answer :

```
function dragover(event) {
 clearTimeout(tid);
 event.stopPropagation();
 event.preventDefault();
 $('.overlay').show();}

function dragleave(event) {
 tid = setTimeout(function(){
 event.stopPropagation();
 $('.overlay').hide();
}, 0);}
```

Setting the timeout to 300, kept a delay when leaving browser window, when setting to 0 : delay AND issue were gone.

I also used the bindings on the window because in Firefox the binding on the .overlay class seem not to work everytime.

```
$(window).bind('dragover', dragover);
$(window).bind('drop', drop);
$(window).bind('dragleave', dragleave);
```

["Here is the full working example in Fiddle"](http://jsfiddle.net/tdhulster/yApUZ/4/)

Comment: 300 ms delay was just a good guess to what is working fine ;-) nice that 0ms still solves the problem!!